# Sitecore.Social NuGet Package Alternatives

Tags: social-connected

We are upgrading a Sitecore 8.2 .NET Solution Code to Sitecore 9.2.

In Sitecore 8.2 Solution, there is a custom code written using Sitecore.Social Module & its sub Modules. However, in Sitecore 9.2, these are not available.

Does Sitecore 9.2 handles these in a separate way? While upgrade, can we discard this customization area? Please provide some leads to explore more on this.

Comment: social conntect was deprecated in 9.You will have to discard this customization , unless there is something specific in there.
You can use the https://sitecore.namics.com/2019/04/29/sitecore9-socialmedia-integration-socialconnected-module/ .

Comment: Thanks Abhay. We have discarded this area completely, as it was an old implementation with nothing specific.